# How can i run shellexecute with a variable?

Tags: delphi, variables, shellexecute

I try to execute a command in shell via delphi but it won't work.
I use this script:

```
var
shellexecommand:string;
begin
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/C ' + shellexecommand + ' > output.txt', nil, SW_HIDE);
end;
```

But i get the error:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(329): E2010 Incompatible types: 'PWideChar'
>   and 'AnsiString'

Also if i change string to pwidechar is doesn't work.
How can i fix this?

Comment: You might be better with CreateProcess here. Particularly if you actually want the output of the other process in the parent and don't need the text file to endure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var
  shellexecommand:string;
begin
  // shellexecommand := ....
  shellexecommand := '/C ' + shellexecommand + ' > output.txt';
  ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', PChar(shellexecommand), nil, SW_HIDE);
end;
```

Comment: Instead of PWideChar, you should use PChar - this will make it compatible with both Unicode and non-Unicode versions of Delphi (Chris edited the answer to do this while I wrote it :-)). And you don't need to first "calculate" the string - you can use PChar(' /C '+ShellExecCommand+' >output.txt')

Comment: @HeartWare - ah, great minds think alike or something like that! ;-) I made the edit as you were adding your comment - hope SimaWB doesn't mind.